# Select an option from autocomplete and focus on the selected item in div in angular

Tags: angular, dom, onfocus, viewchild

I want to implement a search feature where I want to select an option from mat-autocomplete and after selecting that element, I want to focus on the selected text in div.

I have implemented it in the following way:-
The HTML form:-

```
  <mat-form-field fxFlex="70%" appearance="outline" fxFlexOffset="20%">
    <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
    <input matInput type="text" placeholder="Search Assignments" formControlName="assignmentTitleValue" [matAutocomplete]="assignmentsList" #assignmentTitleValue>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-autocomplete #assignmentsList="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of assignmentTitle; trackBy: option" [value]="option" >{{option}}</mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</form>
```

```
    *ngFor="let assignment of assignmentDetails; let index; trackBy: assignment"
  >
  <div >
          {{ assignment.title }}
        </div>
```

The ts file is:-

```
export class ProgressTimelineComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges,AfterViewInit{

assignmentTitle = [];
 onSelectionChanged(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
    this.assignmentTitleValue = event.option.value; 
  }

  @ViewChild('assignmentTitleValue') inputEl: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.inputEl.nativeElement.focus();

  }
```

I am able to get the selected option from mat-autocomplete which I have stored in this.assignmentTitleValue. 
I want that whatever value I select from the list It should be focused on the particular list in div.

```
<div>
{{assignment.title}}
</div>
```

I have tried many ways. But I am not able to achieve it. 
Where I am doing wrong? Please suggest.